# Can not using foreign table in DBunit

Tags: postgresql, spring-mvc, mybatis, dbunit

My project is using SpringMVC, MyBatis, and PostgreSql.

In postgres, I have 2 servers: sv1, sv2.

I imported a table from sv2 into sv1 using:

`import foreign schema public limit to (tbl2) from server sv2 into public;`

But, when using DBUnit to do testing, I cannot insert data into the foreign table tbl2. The exception is:

> ERROR org.dbunit.database.DatabaseDataSet - Table 'tbl2' not found in tableMap=org.dbunit.dataset.OrderedTableNameMap

How can I use foreign table in DBUnit?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to configure the `DatabaseConfig`.

`databaseConfig.setProperty(PROPERTY_TABLE_TYPE, [array of string with table types]);`

or

`databaseConfig.setTableType([array with table types]);`

or configure your bean and add property

```
<property name="tableType">
  <array value-type="java.lang.String">
  <value>TABLE</value>
  <value>FOREIGN TABLE</value>
 </array>
</property>
```

**You can see the whole map of table types if you go to any of the implementations DatabaseMetadata and look for "TABLE"**.